# java swing won't display

Tags: java, swing, animation, graphics, awt

I'm currently trying to add animation to a program that has various objects moving around and interacting in a 2D space. I've finally gotten to where the timer works, and the program has the objects moving and interacting the way I want them to...but the display panel it opens remains frustratingly blank. I've been trying to use code from examples found online, but I must still be missing something...

```
    public class Populus2 extends JPanel 
{
    /**
     * @param args
     */

        static float[] xCoordinates;
        static float[] yCoordinates;
        static int duration;
        static int iteration = 1;
        static int graphSize = 500;
        ..............

        static JFrame frame;
        static JLabel lbl;  
        JPanel panel;
        static Timer timer;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            final Populus2 pop = new Populus2();

            frame = new JFrame("Animation Frame");
            lbl = new JLabel();
            Panel panel = new Panel();
            panel.add(lbl);
            frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.setSize(graphSize, graphSize);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            ActionListener timeStep = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    System.out.println("at time " + iteration);
                    spendTime();
                    pop.repaint();
                    if(iteration>duration)
                        timer.stop();
                }
            };

        timer = new Timer(100, timeStep);
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();      
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paint(g);
        System.out.println("******PAINT******\n******PAINT******\n******PAINT******\n******PAINT******\n******PAINT******\n******PAINT******\n******PAINT******\n******PAINT******\n******PAINT******\n******PAINT******\n******PAINT******\n******PAINT******\n******PAINT******\n******PAINT******\n");
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        paintCell(g, 1);  //eventually, I want to call this method for every "cell" in the program
        g.drawLine(30, 30, 80, 80);  //this line's basically a test to see if I can display anything at all
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();
    }


      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintCell(Graphics graphics, int cellNumber)
    {
        graphics.setColor(Color.black);
        graphics.fillOval((int)(graphSize*xCoordinates[cellNumber]/size), (int)(graphSize*yCoordinates[cellNumber]/size), 5, 5);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for(int i = 0; i < types.length; i++)
            paintCell(g, i);
    }


    public static void spendTime()
    {
        //advances the iteration counter and recalculates the coordinates of all the cells
    }

}
```

Ultimately, I want the program, on each iteration of the timer, to call paintCell() for every one of the cells in the simulation, each one representing a moving object. For now, though, the screen remains blank. The message I had paint() calls through System.out.println() doesn't display, for the record.
Thoughts?

Comment: Do you call repaint() inside the timer?

Comment: Well, I call pop.repaint() within the timeStep ActonListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've been trying to use code from examples found online, but I must still be missing something...

Don't use AWT suggestions in a Swing program. Swing is different from AWT. Don't use a Panel. In Swing you use a `JPanel`. In Swing your override the `paintComponent()` method, not the paint() method. Right now your code attempts to override both methods.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and proper examples.

```
frame.setSize(graphSize, graphSize);
```

Don't use frame.setSize() the frame size includes the borders and title bar so your graph will not be the size you want. Instead, override the `getPreferredSize()` of the JPanel where you do the custom painting to return the size of the panel. Then you would do `frame.pack()`.

But the reason the panel doesn't show is because you don't add the panel to the frame.

```
//frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(pop, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

The code below does nothing since the label has no value. You should be using a JPanel, but there is no need for the panel since you can add a label directly to the content pane of the frame.

```
lbl = new JLabel();
Panel panel = new Panel();
panel.add(lbl);
```